# How many bits is the fraction part of a double?

Tags: computer-science

I'm reading Computer Organization Fifth Edition by Patterson/Henessy and I'm confused about this passage:

[image]

For the fraction, isn't the number of bits 19 and not 20? 0-18 is 19 bits right? What is a significand? My book never defines it. Also, when they say "number" do they mean fraction? Is the fraction 24 bits long in single precision and 53 bits in double?

Answer (score 1):

Your chart appears to have mistakenly shifted the line separating the exponent from the fraction by one place. The exponent is correctly labeled as being 11 bits, but is erroneously shown with 12 bits.

The chart also separates the format onto two lines. The second line contains 32 bits that are a continuation of the fraction. 20 bits on the first line + 32 bits on the second line gives 52 bits.

See the Wikipedia article on [Double-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for a chart that isn't wrapped onto two lines.

`Significand` is defined in the image text you posted. An implicit leading '1' bit is added to the 52-bit fraction, to give a 53-bit significand.